# getting data from json in order to fill a datatable

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuex, v-data-table

Good day developers ... I'm trying to fill a data table dynamically using information already fetched through a fetch and previously stored in a variable in my vuex instance and now called as computed property in my applets say I have this:

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "Games",
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      headers:[
             {text:'Game#', value:'Game#'},
             {text:'Players in Game',value:'Players inGame'},
             {text:'Permissions',value:'Permissions'},
             {text:'Results',value:'Results'},

      ],

    };
  },
  components: {
  },
  props: ["gameid"],
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchingJsonEvents", "joinToGame","logOut", "createGame"]),

  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getGamesAll", "getUserLogged"]),
    getGamesAll(){
       return this.$store.getters.getGamesAll.games-------->here is where the json is stored
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchingJsonEvents();
  }
};
</script>
```

and my html tag calling this computed and all else is like this:

```
<v-data-table :search="search" :headers="headers" v-bind:items="getGamesAll">
    <template>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(general, index) in getGamesAll.games" v-bind:key="index">
              <td>Game {{general.id}}:</td>

              <td>xxxxxxxx</td>
              <td>xxxxxxxx</td>
          </tbody>
     </template>
 </v-data-table>
```

but the table doesn't show any result , it worked with  a v-simple-table, but once i try to do it in this way it doesn't....
Any advice .....thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this is unnecessary:

```
getGamesAll(){
 return this.$store.getters.getGamesAll.games
}
```

because you already have it using `mapGetters`:

```
...mapGetters(["getGamesAll", "getUserLogged"]),
```

if your getter `getGamesAll` have data then this should simply work:

```
<tr v-for="(general, index) in getGamesAll.games" v-bind:key="index">
```

Comment: it doesn't with this kind of table ....i already tested with a v-simple-table and works perfect ....

Comment: @EnriqueGF really curious about this now, let's say that v-simple-table has issue but I hope that when you drop you code this way `<div> getGamesAll.games</div>` then see all your data coming in the browser, right? If yes, then you may try this, just add `if` condition around `v-data-table`, eg: `<div v-if="getGamesAll.games"> <v-data-table .... >.... </v-data-table></div>`